# Не работает Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: windows, ide

При запуске среды выдается окно: "Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application." И все. Переустановка не помогает, пробовал несколько раз непосредственно переустанавливать, и удалять всё с помощью Revo Uninstaller, не спасает ничего. Просматривал с Dependency walker на тему недостающих библиотек -- все на месте. Обновления системы установлены. Система -- Windows XP SP3. Продукт -- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, но с Professional проблема та же.

Сразу сообщаю: установка предыдущих версий или других сред -- не вариант.

Comment: что то вот не нравится ей в ХР, может семерку поставите?

Comment: Нескромный вопрос - пиратчину ставите?
Могу сказать одно: 2010-я у меня точно работала, но после того как я поставил все опции с диска. К тому же, я ставил на 2003 server, а не на XP. Хотя, в целом, ОСи для дома одинаковые.

Comment: Ответ на все комментарии: Студия раньше работала. Хотя насчёт пиратчины... Я скачал из Сети образ, там был заодно и ключ. Но, опять-таки, некоторое время студия работала. И сразу: включена ли сеть, или нет, результат один и тот же: ошибка с завершением работы, то есть проверка кода по сети с этим явно не связана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось несколько иначе. Родной инсталлятор лежит в C:\Documents and Settings\__ALEX\Рабочий стол\X16-42552VS2010UltimTrial1. Оттуда я и всё устанавливал. Напоследок нашел файл setup.exe в C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU\setup.exe. Решил напоследок запустить: ведь и терять нечего. Как не странно, после очередной полной переустановки заработало! Правда, в чём разница, я так и не понял.

Answer (score 2):

в папке C:Program FilesMicrosoft Visual Studio 10.0Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone  - ENULogs лежат логи установки и работы; там должна быть более подробная информация о вашей ошибке (на мою версию VS не обращайте внимания, у вас должна быть соответствующая)

Comment: У меня по адресу C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU\\logs находятся только логи установки. При проверке этих логов меня ничто вроде не насторожило. На случай я переименовал папку logs в logs000 и запустил среду: а вдруг, появится новая папка logs с логом запуска. Ничего: никаких логов работы Студия, видимо, не успевает создать...

Comment: ещё такой нюанс: на XP 64 bit она не работает. Надеюсь у вас не 64 bit?

Comment: Нет. И, снова-таки, среда раньше работала. А вот после каких действий перестала работать -- не помню)))...

Comment: http://computersplace.net/articles-review/cannot-find-one-or-more-components-please-reinstall-the-application.html что это проблема с файлом ATL90.dll но там студия 2008, а у вас 2010, да и вообще может быть в другом проблема. Но всё таки попробуйте- вдруг получится

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте переустановить не студию, а .Net Framework.

Comment: при установке студии, устанавливается также нужный ей .NET framework